# How do I tell what version my Steam edition of The Witcher 2 is?

Tags: steam, the-witcher-2

I'm stuck on the Kayran and I just want to download a trainer and kill it in godmode, but the trainers I've seen are version-specific and I can't tell which is right for me.

How do I tell which version of the game I have?

Comment: Cheats are for the weak

Answer (score 3):

This is a generic solution you can use to determine the version of the game's executable on the steam library.

1. Go to the steam library
2. Right click on the game of interest
3. Select Properties
4. Under the local files tab click browse local files..
5. Right-click on the game's executable
6. Select Properties
7. Under the details tab it should have information regarding the version you're running

On the default settings Steam will continuously try to update the game to the latest version, so it is likely that the version you're running is the latest one available.

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 1):

(also using Steam myself) I've tried the suggestion by Wr4ith and unfortunately for me it doesn't seem so simple. Viewing the properties of witcher2.exe it says version 0.0.0.0

Now, in the README.TXT file it says "Version 3.2 Corrections/Amendments (18th June 2012)...etc...etc..." however it doesn't specifically state anywhere that the game is version 3.2, so I can only assume that what I have is v3.2 which would mean that Steam isn't keeping it completely up to date, as the latest version is v3.3 that I am currently downloading from http://redkit.cdprojektred.com/index.php?c=download

(there's also a v3.4 patch but from what I understand this is for the Editor only, but I'm installing it too just for good measure)

---and as I was typing out this whole reply, I was installing 3.3 and then 3.4, and now that I'm done, the version on the EXE file now says "3.4.4.1" so there's some confirmation I guess.